# Remote Desktop TSWEB port

Tags: windows, iis, remote-desktop, tsweb

I'm thinking about using the TSWEB addon for IIS as a remote access solution for some users, but I have a question:  does it keep everything routed on port 80, does the activeX control it relies on open a new connection on the normal remote desktop port, or does something else happen?

One of the things I'm hoping to gain from this (not the only thing) is to not have to open the extra firewall ports to the outside from that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 3389 will still be used for RDP when using the TSWEB add-on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using server 2008 you should look into TS gateway. It allows connecting into your organisation through port 443 (an SSL tunnel) so it's nice and secure, and just uses 'standard' ports. It behaves just like normal RDP. I believe the associated TS web interface will also use port 443.

There are a couple of minor drawbacks though, the main one being clients must have version 6.1 of the RDP client install on their machine. This means they need one of the following:

- XP SP3
- XP SP2 with the RDP 6.1 update installed
- Vista SP1

If you can get around this, we've found TS gateway to be excellent!

Comment: I just want to add, that in case of Windows XP, ActiveX component of Web Access seems not to work until you delete some registry keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings: 

{4eb89ff4-7f78-4a0f-8b8d-2bf02e94e4b2} 

{7390f3d8-0439-4c05-91e3-cf5cb290c3d0} 

You need to fully delete those nodes, then Web Access ActiveX starts working.